# How to check if date falls between two dates and return value from corresponding row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to get this thing to work, unsuccessfully. I have a spreadsheet with a lot of values, but **I need to assign to which account year a date of an incident falls under**. Account year is defined in a table containing start date, end date and account year. I have managed to get it to work with a table containing four different account years, but the formula breaks when attempting to use it on another table with account years. The table in which I need the output is in different sheet than the table with Start date, End date and Account year (HD_Roi).

Here is the formula I have been using:

`=LOOKUP([@[PURCHASE_DT]],HD_Roi/(HD_Roi[Start date]<=[@[PURCHASE_DT]])/(HD_Roi[End date]>=[@[PURCHASE_DT]]),HD_Roi[UWY])`

1. Purchase_dt = incident date
2. HD_Roi = table with start, end, account yr
3. UWY = account year

The table in question:

[image]

The table which works flawlessly:

[image: Unproblematic table]

The error I keep getting is #N/A, pic of

[image: formula evaluation]

(note:VLKpn! is name of sheet containing lookup tables, lookup value in this case is 07/01/2020)

What I managed to gather so far is that it breaks down as soon as it goes into the 2020 UWY range. I can't understand why. Formatting is equal across all tables (MM/DD/YY) and UWY is formated as general.

Is there any other way I can get this thing to work?

Thanks

Comment: does this helps you? https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/956-excel-date-falls-between-two-dates.html

Comment: and please remove all unnecessary information from the post and leave only the relevant things (all the background story is not relevant)

Comment: Not really, however I did manage to fix it by not using table and column names and replacing it with ranges:
=LOOKUP(2,1/(VLKpn!$F$11:$F$15<=Sheet1!K18)/(VLKpn!$G$11:$G$15>=Sheet1!K18),VLKpn!$H$11:$H$15)

I honestly can't tell what's up with this because I did use this exact formula, just with table names, for sake of clarity.